# XSL / XSL-FO: Different formatting of a block depending on its page position on PDF page

Tags: pdf, xslt, formatting, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm new in this mailing list, so please apologize any of my wrongdoings.

FOP 1.1

Question: Is there any condition to find the **position** of a text-block in on PDF **page**.

**This is the problem**:

I need to change the formatting of a title-block depending on its position on the page.

- If the title-block appears somewhere in the (vertical) middle of the page, I want to add a line on top of it.
- if the title-block appears at the beginning/top of a page the line must not appear

Does XSL-FO have a way to do that?

Comment: Which rendering engine do you intend to use (FOP, Antenna House, ...) ?

Answer (score 0):

From http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-xsl-fo/2015Sep/0002.html:

> I used a white background on the 
>   fo:region-before and a negative margin on the title to 'push' the 
>   'border-before' of the title under the fo:region-before.
>
> This requires that the FO processor supports negative values of 
>   'margin-top', which is allowed but not required (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#margin-top).  It also requires 
>   that the FO processor will 'paint' the fo:region-before after painting 
>   the fo:region-body.